# DataGrid view pass row ID to textbox on another page

Tags: .net, datagridview

I want to be able to select a project name in a datagridview. It would then open up a projects page automatically put that `projectID` or `Projectname` in a textbox. I would then be able to filter the data correctly automatically. Any ideas?

Not sure where to start on this..